# How to add custom customer attribute in custom tab in customer edit page of admin in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I have created custom customer attribute successfully. Which are showing under account information tab of customer edit in admin.

I want to show them in my custom tab.

Comment: found the solution for this?

Comment: Any body know solution ?

Comment: I need a solution, too.

Comment: the attributes under the account information tab are rendered generically based on a setting you can add to the customer attribute (include in forms, it's an own mapping table). If you have a custom tab, you have to render it yourself, but the "how" depends on how you implemented the custom tab

Answer (score 0):

To create a new tab in the admin customer edit, create a xml in the following path

Step 1:

> /app/code/Vendorname/modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml

```
<body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
         <block class="Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Test" name="customer_edit_tab_test" >
          <action method="setTabLabel">
              <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Test Tab</argument>
          </action>
        </block>
      </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Step 2:
Create a block file in the below path to load the contents when the tab is clicked

> /app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements TabInterface
{

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __(‘Tab label’);
    }
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __(‘Tab Title’);
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Tab class getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }
    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
    //replace the tab with the url you want
        return $this->getUrl('test/*/test', ['_current' => true]);
    }
    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your new test tab will be added to customer edit left side menu.

Comment: how to write this url ? i have controller name `Index.php` and adminhrml route name `hello`